# Exibir objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, json

tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
"json": [
    {
      "nome": "Meu Nome",
      "amigos": [
        {
          "amigo": "João",
          "idade": 20
        }            
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Tenho também o seguinte for:

```
this.qtd = data.json.length;

for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
                this.retorno += 'Nome: ' + data.json[i].nome;
        this.retorno += 'Amigo:' + JSON.stringify(data.json[i].amigos);
}
```

Gostaria de saber como exibir na tela o nome somente o nome do amigo?
Pois quando faço com "JSON.stringify()", o mesmo retorna com as chaves, aspas, etc.

Como posso pegar apenas o nome do amigo?

Abaixo o código completo:

```js
function dados(){
 var qtd;
 var retorno;


 json.prototype.resgatarValores = function(){
  $('#resultado').html('loading...');

  $.getJSON('http://www.site.com/arquivo.json', function(data){
   this.qtd = data.json.length;
   this.retorno = '';  

   for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
    this.retorno += 'Nome: ' + data.json[i].nome + '<br />';    
    this.retorno += 'Amigo: ' + JSON.stringify(data.json[i].amigo) + '<br />';   
    
   }

   $('#resultado').html(this.retorno);
  });

 }

}

var obj = new dados();
obj.resgatarValores();
```

Comment: [Dessa](https://jsfiddle.net/21tpy4dn/) forma?

Comment: Lucas, seria isso sim.

O problema é que já tenho o código assim:

for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
 this.retorno += 'Nome: ' + data.json[i].nome + '<br />';
}

Como eu posso inserir dentro desse for? Pode me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Edson, tente postar o código com a função toda, o `this` do `this.qtd` se refere a que? também precisamos saber da onde veio esse `data`. Essas informações serão úteis para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Caique, postei o código completo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método  [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para percorrer os `arrays` de seu `objeto json`.

```js
var json = [
  {
    "nome": "Meu Nome",
    "amigos": [
      {
        "amigo": "João",
        "idade": 20
      }            
    ]
  }
];

json.forEach(function(item) {
    item.amigos.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.amigo);
    });
});
```

Comment: O problema é que já tenho o código assim: 

for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){ this.retorno += 'Nome: ' + data.json[i].nome + '<br />'; 
} 

Como eu posso inserir dentro desse for? Pode me ajudar? 

Obrigado.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e inclua o código com esse for e como ele é chamado, para que possamos entender melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: Caique, me desculpe sou iniciante em JSON e realmente não soube me expressar. Editei meu post. Se puder me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer dessa forma:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
                this.retorno += 'Nome: ' + data.json[i].nome;
        this.retorno += 'Amigo:' + JSON.stringify(data.json[i].amigos[i].amigo);
}
```

Comment: vai retornar apenas o nome dos amigos

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou dessa maneira.

Comment: [link]var json = [
    {
      "nome": "Meu Nome",
      "amigos": [
        {
          "amigo": "João",
          "idade": 20
        }            
      ]
    }
  ]
undefined
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
                'Nome: ' + json[i].nome;
        'Amigo:' + JSON.stringify(json[i].amigos[i].amigo);
}
"Amigo:"João""

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```js
$.getJSON('www.site.com.br/arquivo.json', function(data){
  
 this.qtd = data.json.length;
 this.retorno = '';

 for(i in data.json){
     this.retorno += 'Nome: ' + data.json[i].nome + '<br />';

        for (j in data.json[i].amigos){
            this.retorno += 'TXT: ' + data.json[i].amigos[j].amigo + '<br />';
        }    

        this.retorno += '<br />';
    }      

 $('#resultado').html(this.retorno);
});
```

Obrigado à todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dados(){
    var qtd;
    var retorno;


    json.prototype.resgatarValores = function(){
        $('#resultado').html('loading...');

        $.getJSON('http://www.site.com/arquivo.json', function(data){
            this.qtd = data.json.length;
            this.retorno = '';      

            for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
                this.retorno += 'Nome: ' + data.json[i].nome + '<br />';                
                this.retorno += 'Amigo: ' + JSON.stringify(data.json[i].amigo) + '<br />';          
                
            }

            $('#resultado').html(this.retorno);
        });

    }

}

var obj = new dados();
obj.resgatarValores();
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
var json = [
  {
    "nome": "Meu Nome",
    "amigos": [
      {
        "amigo": "João",
        "idade": 20
      }            
    ]
  }
];

json.forEach(function(item) {
    item.amigos.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.amigo);
    });
});
```

Comment: Parece ser exatamente o mesmo código [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256835/5878). Qual foi sua intenção ao responder?